# How to disable pop-out option in pdf viewer with google drive embedded iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf

I've embed pdf in my website using iframe google drive pdf viewer, below is my codes I've used

It works fine, but I want to remove the pop-out button appear on the top right corner in my website so that, viewers can't view outside my page[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvpmC.jpg)

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve this problem with the following `iframe` `sandbox` attribute value:

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-forms allow-modals allow-orientation-lock allow-pointer-lock allow-presentation allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation"
        src=""
        width="640"
        height="480"
        https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="<url-your-pdf>"?t="1625427767140"></iframe>
```

Comment: Brilliant, saved me a massive headache there

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        iframe{
  height:100vh;
}
    </style>

</head>
<body>



<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf&embedded=true" width="100%" height="100vh" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" ></iframe>

<div style="width: 80px; height: 80px; position: absolute; opacity: 0; right: 0px; top: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
<!-- </div> -->
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below:
Using a hidden element on top of pop-out button makes it inaccessible. Or, if want to hide, remove opacity and set the background-color.

```
<div style="width: 640px; height: 480px; position: relative;"> 
      <iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=YOUR PDF/DOC FILE URL &embedded=true"   width="640" height="480" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" seamless=""></iframe>
      <div style="width: 40px; height: 40px; position: absolute; opacity: 0; right: 12px; top: 12px;">&nbsp;</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answers do work, but with caveats.

1. Just the iFrame `sandbox` prevents the button from working, but the button still shows.
2. Just masking the button to prevent it from being clicked works, but the button still shows.
3. *To disable the button and prevent it from showing:*

   `<div style="position: relative;">`

   `<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https://example.com/file.pdf &embedded=true" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin"></iframe>`

   `<div style="width:40px; height:40px; position:absolute; background:white; right:12px; top: 12px;">&nbsp;</div>`

   `</div>`